# How to check datetime-local input field is not less than other datetime-local field

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I am creating a form, where i am using `datetime-local` for 2 input fields - StartDate and EndDate.

How can I ensure EndDate is not less than StartDate. I wrote below JS, but it is not working on selecting date / or even onclick on submit button of the page.

Please advise, and thanks for taking your time to read through this :)

```js
function checkDate() {
  var dateString = document.getElementById('StartDate').value;
  var dateString2 = document.getElementById('EndDate').value;
  var DateStart = new Date(dateString);
  var DateEnd = new Date(dateString2);
  if (DateEnd > DateStart) {
    alert("End date cannot be less than Start date.");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

```html
<input type="datetime-local" class="form-control name_list" name="StartDate" id="StartDate" required="required" onclick="checkDate()" />
</div>
<div class="col-lg-1 mb-0">
  <h6>Deployment End *</h6>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 mb-0">
  <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control name_list" name="EndDate" id="EndDate" required="required" onclick="checkDate()" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the click event handler will only activate when you click on the form, firing when you do not have any of the useful information. The alternative would be 'onchange' which will fire when you complete the input.

```
<input type="datetime-local" class="form-control name_list" name="StartDate" id="StartDate" required="required" onchange="checkDate()" />
<input type="datetime-local" class="form-control name_list" name="EndDate" id="EndDate" required="required" onchange="checkDate()" />
```

If you want to make sure your end date is in the future compared to your start date you need to swap the comparison operator.

```
if (DateEnd < DateStart) {
    alert("End date cannot be less than Start date.");
    return false;
}
  return true;
```